# How to overload stream operators in C++

Tags: c++

I need class to overload stream operators << (inserter) and >> (extractor)
that insert or extract a private integer variable

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, add the `homework` tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
private:
    int i;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& rhs)
    {
        os << rhs.i;
        return os;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, C& rhs)
    {
        is >> rhs.i;
        return is;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << c << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To your own class? Have a look at this link: http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

In short, you'll add something like this to your class:

```
ClassName & operator<<(int rhs) {
    mylocalint = rhs;
}
ClassName & operator>> (int *rhs) {
    *rhs = mylocalint;
}
```

Comment: not if he means for ifstream/ofstream

Comment: I assumed that wasn't what he meant because he wants to deal with a private variable, but I guess there's some possibility he means inputting a variable from stdin and the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

```
class myclass {
private: int variable;
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const myclass& inst);
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& out, myclass& inst);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const myclass& inst)
{
    return out << inst.variable;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, myclass& inst)
{
    return in >> inst.variable;
}

int main() {
    myclass obj;
    std::cin >> obj;
    std::cout << obj;
}
```

Comment: Great minds think alike it seems :)